# How to clear all SpellBox controls in WinForm

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I have a `WinForm` project which utilises `SpellBoxes` from `WPF`. I am now creating a function to clear all of my fields, and TextBoxes in the class. The `textBoxes` are actually `SpellBoxes` intergrated into the project which is why I think I am getting this problem. From my understanding this will be best achieved by looping through all of my controls with something similar to this:

```
public void ClearControls()
        {
            foreach (Control control in panel1.Controls)
            {
                if (control is SpellBox)
                {
                    SpellBox txt = (SpellBox)control;
                    txt.Text = "";
                }


            }
        }
```

And then called on  a click event, `ClearControls();`

However due to me using SpellBoxes I cannot seem to even iterate through, it’s as if they’re not even recognised. The above function works with TextBox’s, but not with `spellBox’s`.  If anyone could give me some indication as to why this is happening, I would be grateful. Thanks in advance

Comment: This search is only one level deep.  Are your `SpellBox`es nested in other controls?

Comment: yes @ adv12  they're nested inside a panel if thats what you mean

Comment: You mean, they're nested inside a panel that is itself nested inside `panel1`?  Because if so, that's your problem.  If they're direct children of `panel1`, then my hunch is wrong and this isn't your problem.

Comment: Also, it's a bit confusing that you seem to be talking about WPF and WinForms at the same time.  Are you mixing the two, or did you tag this question wrong?

Comment: yes thats correct I have `panel1`with all of my control panels nested in. `   panel1` actually has a further 4 panels on with all differnt controls on so  i have 4 seperate panels.

Comment: its because I am using a WPF spellbox in my WinForm project

Comment: Okay, from your comment I'm still not entirely sure which control is the immediate parent of your `SpellBox`es, but if it's not `panel1`, you need to either search the actual parent control or do a recursive search.

Comment: Re: WPF/WinForms, your question says this is in a WPF project.  Did you mean to say "I have a WinForms project which utilizes SpellBoxes from WPF"?

Comment: Yes thats right I have Just edited it sorry for the confusion. I have managed to iterate through half of my SpellBoxes now by changing the panel. But because the controls are all grouped on seperate panels i dont know how to go through all of them.

Comment: That's what I meant by "do a recursive search."  Here's a Google search that should turn up several examples of how to do this:  https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+recurse+through+controls&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Answer (score 0):

Quick example of a recursive search:

```
public void ClearControls(Control cntr)
{
    foreach (Control control in cntr.Controls)
    {
        if (control is SpellBox)
        {
            control.Text = "";
        }
        else if(control.HasChildren)
        {
            ClearControls(control);
        }
    }
}
```

You start it off by passing in the **Form** itself via `this`:

```
ClearControls(this);
```